# Naming variables for multiple seeding

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to seed multiple things using something like:

```
  users = User.create([

    { user_name: 'Robe22222' },
    { user_name: 'lisaa' },
    { user_name: 'pola' },
    { user_name: 'gilber' },
    { user_name: 'tina' }

  ])
```

but I want to make variable names for everyone so that I can refer to their ID's later when I'm making other variables that connect with them via foreign keys. Is there an easy way to do this without having to

user1 = User.create({ user_name: 'Robe22222' }),

user2 = User.create, etc?

Comment: You can use [factory bot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot_rails)

Comment: `users` is already a variable, an array that you can use to refers to any record, users[0],users[1] ....

Answer (score 1):

You're creating multiple Users, and you assigned them to a variable called `users`. The `users` variable should look something like this.

```rb
users
=> [#<User id: 1, user_name: "Robe22222">, #<User id: 2, user_name: "lisaa">, ...and so on]
```

Then, depending on what you want to do, you can get a User's `id` from the `users` array by using any of the following.

```rb
# Source: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html
Model.create(xxx: xxx, user_id: users.third.id)
```

```rb
Model.create(xxx: xxx, user_id: users[2].id)
```